# mvc debugging with internet explorer

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2013

I had to reload my computer and I was able to choose what browser I was able to test my MVC application in Visual Studio 2013 but it seems that I am missing something.

This is the option I had before:

[image]

And now I do not have that option:

[image]

I have to change my default browser back and forth for this to work and that is a pain.

Anyone know what I am missing?

**IN RESPONSE TO bto.rdz**

I'm not given any browser options when I click the arrow:

[image]

Comment: see that little arrow pointing down? click it, and the browser you select, will run the next times, you can even launch you app in all the browsers avalible

Comment: @bto.rdz I have added a print screen. Am I go to into Browse With each time I want to debug? Is that what you are referring to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I went and checked my Visual Studio 2013 and was surprised that mine was doing the same thing. I only had the start option. I investigated the standard menu and after a little guess work I figured out what happened. Right click your web project in your solution. then select it as the start up application. As soon as I did that I got my browser choices back.

Comment: If I have multiple start up projects I cannot set a default browser?

Comment: @ErocM: How do you have multiple start up projects for a single solution? Only one should be able to be designated as a startup in any given solution.

Comment: I would bet that if you want the Browser option then you'll need to have a web project set as your startup project otherwise it won't make since for it to display a list of browsers.